# IOS MKMapView not called delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I had created a `MKMapView` and set delegate for this. But, it's not called delegate for this `MKMapView`.

```
    - (id)initWith_latitudeObject:(NSString *)latitudeObject longitudeObject:(NSString *)longitudeObject fromUser:(NSString *)fromUser
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _mkMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [_mkMapView setDelegate:self];
        MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
        mapRegion.center.latitude = [latitudeObject doubleValue];
        mapRegion.center.longitude = [longitudeObject doubleValue];
        mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
        mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
        _mkMapView.region = mapRegion;
        [self addSubview:_mkMapView];
        [self getLocationMapView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It's not call:

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView fullyRendered:(BOOL)fullyRendered{
UIImage *img = [self renderToImage:mapView];
```

}
How to I can resolve this problem! Please help me.

I had set delegate for this, but it's not called delegate for this `MKMapView`

Comment: you have set delegate for mapView and implement method for mapview2.

Comment: No! I set delegate for [mapView setDelegate:self];

Comment: I am telling you same thing. in your delegate method , you've written mapview2.

Comment: this is delegate for my mapview